# Programming: Difference between concept and construct

Tags: terminology

When it comes to programming what is the difference between concept and construct for describing "patterns" used in multiple languages?
e.g. are "immutable data structures" or "pattern matching" concepts or constructs?

Comment: you are asking for the difference between two words which both have multiple meanings (even in computer science) hence your question is ambiguous (in addition to being somewhat opinion-based). None of this is to say that it isn't an *interesting* question. My take is that constructs are on the pseudo-code level and are used to flesh-out concepts, which are higher-order abstractions.

Comment: SO is for specific technical programming questions

Answer (score 2):

To start off, concepts are ways to explain something that we observe and that we try to explain. Construct is a little bit created in the opposite order. We "construct" a concept to be able to work with a situation and explain somethings that are not directly observed or deduced.

Immutable data structures is a concept since it qualifies something that is "tangible" or actually invisible with your eye but have a precise mechanic in the computer. "Pattern matching" is a concept of really specific procedures.

Now I guess that when you think about "construct" you also refer to programming "constructs" like operators (like +, -, *). In this case they are also concepts called "constructs" but shouldn't be considered to be the equivalent to "construct"/"concepts" concepts ;).

Hopefully, this helped you sort those words out.

Dan